# How to accelerate a convolution (laplace kernel) with FFT

Tags: fourier-transform, fast-multipoles

I have the following computation I'm trying to program and accelerate with the FFT.

$$
\phi(x) = \sum_{y \in Y} K(x, y) q(x), \> \> \forall x \in X
$$

Where $X$ and $Y$ are sets of Cartesian coordinates in 2D. and $K(x, y) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \ln(\sqrt{(x_1 - y_1)^2 + (x_2 - y_2)^2})$.

I want to accelerate this convolution using the FFT, however I'm a little confused as to exactly how to formulate it.

In my case $x$ and $y$ denote points discretising the surfaces of two squares (for those who know it, this arises in the Kernel Independent formulation of the FMM algorithm).

I know from theory that the fourier transfrom can be applied to a kernel of this kind with the following reasoning, to accelerate the convolution

$$
q(x) * K(x-y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} q(y) K(x-y)dy
$$
$$
q(x) * K(x-y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} q(y) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left ( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \hat{K}(\omega)e^{-i\omega(x-y)} d\omega\right ) dy
$$

$$
q(x) * K(x-y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \hat{K}(\omega) \left ( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}q(y) e^{i\omega y} dy \right ) dx
$$

$$
q(x) * K(x-y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \hat{K}(\omega) \hat{q}(\omega) d
$$

and that therefore,

$$
F[f * g](x) = F[K(x)]F[q(x)]
$$

In practice I don't think I'm formulating the calculation correctly.

I'm calculating the kernel as follows,

```py
def K(x, y):
    diff = (x[0]-y[0])**2+(x[1]-y[1])**2
    return 1/2*np.pi * np.log(np.sqrt(diff))
```

and for two sets of target/source points

```py
yc = np.array([1, 1])
xc = np.array([3, 1])
y = np.array([
    [0, 0],
    [1, 1],
    [1, 0],
    [0, 1]
]) + yc

x =  np.array([
    [0, 0],
    [1, 1],
    [1, 0],
    [0, 1]
]) + xc
```

I'm calculating the fourier transforms as,

```py
# Fourier transform of kernel values wrt to origin
origin = np.array([0, 0, 0])
y_s = np.zeros(len(y))
for i, source in enumerate(y):
    y_s[i] = K(origin, source)

y_k = fft(y_s)

# Fourier transform of signal
q_s = np.zeros(len(y))
for i, source in enumerate(y):
    q_s[i] = 1.0
q_k = fft(q_s)
```

And performing the convolution/inverse transform.

```py
conv_fft = (y_k * q_k)
conv_fft = ifft(conv_fft)
```

I'm not getting the same answer as with direct calculation, but don't understand why.

This is my code for direct convolution

```py
conv_x_direct = np.zeros(len(x))
for i, yi in enumerate(y):
    conv_sum = 0
    for j, xi in enumerate(x):
        conv_sum += K(yi, xi)
    conv_x_direct[i] = conv_sum
```

Comment: The Fourier approach only works if you actually have a convolution, i.e., $K(x,y)=\bar K(x-y)$. But you don't.

Comment: I do have a convolution the operand of the kernel describes a norm over the difference between two vectors, x and y are the difference in the x and y components respectively.

Comment: Then I don't understand your notation. The definition of $K(x,y)$ under the first formula is clearly not of the form $K(x,y)=\bar K(x-y)$.

Comment: Sure, I was being unclear, I will change it now.

Comment: Ah, that's better. I note that `1/2*np.pi` is not the $\frac{1}{2\pi}$ you have in the formula, but that is probably not what you mean when you say "I'm not getting the same answer as with direct calculation". It might help if you described what you see and what you expect for a simple test case. For example, what happens if you choose $q=const$?